# Custom cucumber expression highlighted

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

I've written custom cucumber transformer and accordingly the RegExp.

```
typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType(
        "list_of_event_templates",
        "([0-9]+) event templates of (.*)",
        List.class,
        new GenericRecordListTransformer<>()
));
```

Everything works fine, however the cucumber highlights all the matching expression in feature file like this:

[image]

But I want to make it readable in terms of parameters:

Expected: generate **100** event templates of **TYPE**

Actual: generate **100 event templates of TYPE**

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `"[0-9]+(?= event templates of)|(?<= event templates of ).*"`?

Comment: That works but then nothing gets highlighted in the feature file, even 100 and TYPE. But I need exactly only them to be highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see such highlighting because you actually define single compound parameter. Hence a plugin highlights all that matches your expression.

The only way to split those values visually is to use two separate parameters: one for number and one for type.

Comment: thanks, that worked